# \vadjust example on Tug.org

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, primitives

I was on Tug.org reading about some of TeX's primitives. I came across this example usage of \vadjust.

```
1. \def\strutA#1#2{\vrule height#1 depth#2 width0pt}
2. \def\ta#1%
3. {%
4.      \strutA{8.5pt}{3.5pt}%
5.      \vadjust
6.      {
7.           \vbox to 0pt
8.           {
9.                \kern-1\baselineskip
10.                \moveleft0.5in\hbox to 0.5in
11.                {
12.                     \strutA{8.5pt}{3.5pt}%
13.                     \hfil#1\kern1em
14.                }
15.                \vss
16.           }%
17.      }%
18. }
19. \hsize=4.75in
20. There are cries, sobs, confusion among the people, and at that moment
21. the cardinal himself, the Grand Inquisitor, passes by the cathedral.
22. He is an old man, almost ninety, tall and erect,\ta{100} with a
23. withered face and sunken eyes, in which there is still a gleam of
24. light. He is not dressed in his brilliant cardinal's robes, as he was
25. the day before, when he was burning the enemies of the Roman
26. Church~\char144 \kern2em\hfill Fyodor Dostoyevsky, {\it The Brothers
27. Karamazov}\par
```

I was having trouble understanding the code, so I ran it and then fiddled around with some of the values. It seems to me that the values used to align the margin vbox vertically with the  main text (or a given line in it), are a bit contrived. I'm wondering if there's a way to ask TeX for the line height of the line that the \vadjust occurs in and use that to set the position of the vbox.

Answer (score 4):

No. The height and depth of the line depends on what is on the line, and what is on the line is decided after the \vadjust material is typeset.

The example uses a strut to make most cases have known height and depth. You don't need \strutA with explicit values for height and depth -- an ordinary \strut would work fine, as long as there is nothing bigger on the line. To elaborate, the box from \vadjust is added to the vertical list without any baseline skip. The height and depth of the struts add up to \baselineskip so, as long as there is no text taller or deeper than the strut, one can align the baselines by kerning up by \baselineskip. Other lengths could be used, as long as

```
upwards kern = depth of strut in text + height of vadjust box
```

Large dimensions could give less ideal page breaks.

The way to make it work more generally, no matter the depth of the text on the line, is to force a page break, have the output routine collect the boxes (using \lastbox), and record the height and depth of the boxes. But once you use the output routine, you wouldn't have to measure heights and depths because the boxes can be combined into one box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Donald. I'm a little confused about which boxes you're referring to when you say "the boxes can be combined into one box." Does to output routine combine the hbox holding the contents of the line with the vbox created with ```\vadjust```?

Comment: I mean the output routine *can* combine those two boxes. The LaTeX output routine uses special negative penalties to trigger the output routine for \marginpar, but the text of the marginpar is saved in a box register rather than on the vertical list in \vadjust. (\vadjust would be beneficial for eliminating lost marginpar errors!) But oh! It may not be safe to grab lines of text with \lastbox because lines can be shifted (in lists). I suspect some tricky luatex extension looking into the last node would be necessary.

Comment: I'm really interested in knowing how that would work, conceptually. Does the LaTeX output routine use negative penalties to ensure a line break occurs right before command \marginpar? And if it then saves the contents of the margin in a box register, how does it then combine them with the main line text where the break occurred?

Comment: LaTeX uses big negative penalties to force an immediate page break where the line in the paragraph will be the last line on the page. It puts the marginpar beside it (potentially shifting the mpar vertically to avoid other mpars) and dumps the page back into the typesetting stream. It detects the penalty at the break from the \outputpenalty parameter. Typesetting ltoutput.dtx might help, or might not.

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind. I really appreciate your help! While playing around with the code I found that if I type just ```\vadjust{\vbox to 0pt{100}}``` (as opposed to all the other stuff), in same spot as before, the top of the text protrudes past the place where I'd expect the lower edge of the previous line to be (not the baseline but the bottom edge). But when I add a strut to the vbox it never goes past that bottom edge, only text seems to. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know what you tried exactly, but the simplest case shows the top of "100" touching the bottom of the characters in the paragraph.